# Not working BoxDecoration Image in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im new in flutter dart app,and I just want to change this bunch of code from `circleAvatar` into `square type` when displaying the image. It's very helpful fo me if anyone know the problem is.

[image]

Below is the code of `CircleAvatar` and I want to change the displaying image into a square shape instead of circle.

```
    File _pickedImage;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: CircleAvatar(    //This is the cirtcle avatar want to change to square tyoe
              radius: 10,
              child: _pickedImage == null ? Text("Picture") : null,
              backgroundImage:
                  _pickedImage != null ? FileImage(_pickedImage) : null,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Pick Image"),
            onPressed: () {
              _showPickOptionsDialog(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is what I've tried, I add BoxDecorator under Container but it causes me an error. `Failed assertion: line 855 pos 14: 'file != null': is not true.`

```
  File _pickedImage;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: _pickedImage != null ? FileImage(_pickedImage) : null,
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Pick Image"),
            onPressed: () {
              _showPickOptionsDialog(context);
            },
          )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `circleAvatar` and use `Container` instead

```
 Widget _imageWidget() {
    if (_pickedImage != null) {
      return Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        child: Text("Picture"),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: FileImage(_pickedImage),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , I tried but I don't know why I'm always getting this error. `package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart': Failed assertion: line 55 pos 15: 'image != null': is not true. `

Comment: Issue was `image` property of `DecorationImage` was called on null. This is wrong. First you have to get value in `_pickedImage` then after you can call `image` property.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine now I just add DecorationImage to pickup the image

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
     image: _pickedImage != null ?
            DecorationImage(
               image: FileImage(_pickedImage), 
               fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ): null,
 ),
```